# white space created by hidden div

Tags: jquery, css

I have three divs contained within a fourth div.

HTML:

```
  <p onclick="Show_1(0)" >1 </a> </p>
  <p onclick="Show_2(0)">2 </a> </p>
  <p onclick="Show_3(0)">3 </a></p>

<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery: (function repeated for other divs)

```
 function Show_3(x){
 $('#1').hide(x);
 $('#2').hide(x);
 $('#3').show(x);   
}
```

CSS:

```
#1, #2, #3{
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: -720px;
    height: auto;
    width: 510px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: medium solid #000;  
}

#container2 { 
    position: relative; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border: ridge; 
    width: 968px; 
    overflow: visible; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
}
```

I use jquery to hide two of the three divs and show one depending on which button is clicked. The three divs are all relatively positioned and I have shifted the divs 1, 2 and 3 so they are all shown in the same location, ie, click a button and div 2 replaces div 1.

The issue I am having is that there is an amount of white space showing below the end of the div that appears to be equal to the height of the div. For example, if I click the button to show div id=1, then the amount of white space below is equal to the height of div id=1.

I think this is occurring because of shifting the div up with a relative position, but I do not know how to correct it with CSS or if I will need to use jquery.

I have not been able to find this exact issue in other questions and any solutions to similar problems haven't worked.

Any suggestions or experience with this problem before? Thanks in advance for any help suggestions.

EDIT.

I was trying to keep it simple, I have added some code above. It is all working well, except for the white space underneath.

Thanks again.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Without some code, you will most likely do not get an answer here.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: How are you hiding the divs? Please show a **complete** code example. A jsFiddle would be a plus.

Comment: I forgot to include the css code for the container and cant seem to add it in now. Here it is:#container2 {
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: ridge;
 width: 968px;
 overflow: visible;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: auto;
}

Comment: @Mick You can do that editing your question. This time I try do it for you ;) Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 3):

It's very difficult as you haven't included any code but from the description of your problem I gather that you are hiding the elements. There are two things you can do to 'hide' elements using CSS (with or without jQuery):

1. Hide
   This will hide the element but it will still take up the same amount of space in your layout because it is still technically there.
2. Display: none
   This will remove the element from the layout entirely meaning it will not affect your layout (unless it has been built with this element in mind).

I would recommend you try using the display: none method by modifying the css of your divs dynamically using jQuery rather than using the stock hide() and show() functions.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

N.B. I would find a better link than w3 fools but can't at the moment as I'm at work.

---

### Revision 1 - Show(), Hide() method

I've knocked something simple together based upon some slight revisions of your code that demonstrates the issue you are encountering (As your code wasn't exactly plug and play for anyone else who may see it and try it). Anybody who looks at the fiddle will see that there is space reserved at the bottom of the container for the hidden elements as suggested in point 1 above.

http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/nezPm/

HTML

```
      <p> <a href="#" id="d1show">1</a> </p>
      <p> <a href="#" id="d2show">2</a> </p>
      <p> <a href="#" id="d3show">3</a></p>

      <div id="container">
        <div id="d1">Hello 1</div>
        <div id="d2">Hi 2</div>
        <div id="d3">Hello 3</div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
      #d1, #d2, #d3{
      position: relative;
      /*left: 180px;
      top: -720px;
      */
      height: auto;
      width: 510px;
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      text-align: justify;
      margin-left: 10px;
      border: medium solid #000;  
      }

      #container { 
      position: relative;
      left: 0px; 
      top: 0px;
      width: auto; 
      height: auto; 
      background-color: #FFFFFF; 
      border: ridge; 
      width: 968px;
      overflow: visible; 
      padding: 0px; 
      margin-top: 0px; 
      margin-right: auto; 
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: auto; 
      }
```

Javascript

```
      $('#d3show').click(function() {
          $('#d1').hide('slow', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
      $('#d2').hide('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $('#d3').show('slow', function() {
       // Animation complete.
     });
     });
```

In the example above only hyperlink 3 will trigger an animation.

---

### Revision 2 - CSS Method

I have now added the css version here that way you can easily compare the two methods:

http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/nY6u3/

The only change from above is the javascript area. You will notice that the extra space is no longer reserved in the div as it is with the show(), hide() method.

Javascript:

```
    $('#d3show').click(function() {
      $('#d1').css('display', 'none');
      $('#d2').css('display', 'none');
      $('#d3').css('display', 'inline');
    });

    $('#d2show').click(function() {
      $('#d1').css('display', 'none');
      $('#d2').css('display', 'inline');
      $('#d3').css('display', 'none');
    });

    $('#d1show').click(function() {
      $('#d1').css('display', 'inline');
      $('#d2').css('display', 'none');
      $('#d3').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

Comment: THanks for your suggestion. I have added code since you made your comment. However, the display none doesn't seem to work. I implemented it as follows:
    function ShowObjective(x){
  $('#feedback').css('display','none');
  $('#aboutPageImage').css('display','none');
  $('#objective2').show(x); 
 }

Comment: I would look at amending the code you are using. In your jquery code above you are targeting elements that don't even exist.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I changed the names in the question to keep it simple - which obviously was a mistake as it hasn't worked - the names in my comment above (#feedback etc) are the actual names of the divs.

Comment: It's generally a good idea never to oversimplify your code on here to the point that it requires lots of re-factoring as I had to do above.

Comment: I've now enclosed two working examples above using each methodology.

Comment: @Mick if you are happy with the solution above, please mark the answer as correct as I've spent quite a bit of time putting together a nice example for other users (granted it's not perfect and can be tidied up a bit).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, and sorry about posting inadequate code, ill learn for next time. Unfortunately the code didn't quite work in my situation but did have an effect - which is more than i was achieving before - so thanks for the ideas. I'll have to get back onto this tomorrow after work. Cheers.

wasn't meant to be saying your code is wrong - just i am too tired to think straight anymore tonight.

Comment: If there is still an issue after this I would suggest it may be caused by some additional css that is enacting upon your div elements that you have not posted here. My revision definitely achieves the effect you described based upon the code you provided.